# single line command to add a word to a quoted variable in a file and report good or bad if it worked

Tags: regex, sed

I've got a file that looks like so:

```
VAR1="one two three"
VAR2="four five six"
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

I am trying to find a command that modifies this file, in place like so:

1. Find the line that matches the regex `/^VAR2=".*?"/`
2. Comment it out
3. Append `#` and then today's date (e.g. `# 2019-02-04`)
4. Duplicate the line but append `test` inside the string and append `#` with today's date to the end of the line

So the end result looks like this:

```
VAR1="one two three"
# VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-04
VAR2="four five six test" # 2019-02-04
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

I am able to do this with this `sed` and it works but I also want it to let me know a status: yes it found the line and did the ask, or no it did not find the line.

```
sed -i -r -e "s/^(VAR2=\".*?)(\")/# \1\2 # $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')\n\1 test\2 # $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')/" file
```

If it matters, the replacement string would never have regex in it.

I am open to better ways to do this. The purpose is basically to edit configuration files and add characters to variable values, and also duplicate the line and comment for backup purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned in comments that op needs to print if a match of line starting with `VAR2` found or not so adding a solution in `awk` now.

```
awk -v dat="$dat" '
/^VAR2.*/{
  found=1
}
found && /^VAR2.*/{
  print "Line starting with VAR2 has been found on Line " FNR "."
  $0="# " $0 " # " dat ORS $0 " # " dat
}
{
  print > "temp"
}
END{
  if(!found){
     print "NO line starting with VAR2 found."
  }
}' Input_file && mv temp Input_file
```

Where `dat` is `awk` variable which has `dat` shell variable's value in it. Output will be as follows.

```
VAR1="one two three"
Line starting with VAR2 has been found on Line 2.
# VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-05
VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-05
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

---

---

Could you please try following. You could create a BASH variable which has the date's value from system and then could use it in `sed` as a neat and clean process.

```
cat << EOF > Input_file
VAR1="one two three"
VAR2="four five six"
VAR3="seven eight nine"
EOF

dat=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
echo $dat

sed "/^VAR2.*/s/^VAR2.*/# & # $dat\n& # $dat/g" Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2019-02-05   ##This value is getting printed from echo command of shell.
VAR1="one two three"
# VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-05
VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-05
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

Comment: This doesn't let me know a status: yes it found the line and did the ask, or no it did not find the line.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, I believe that was not mentioned in post so didn't include it, let me add another solution now.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, please check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: I had mentioned the status request in both the title and in the question: "but I also want it to let me know a status:..." And I see your update but that outputs to screen. I want to make the changes to the file and just output to the screen if it found and changed the line or not.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, not an issue, I have updated my EDIT solution now kindly check and let me know? It will save output into Input_file itself and print number of lines which have match found for VAR2  too, let me know?'

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Perl pie like so:

```
$ cat yourfile.txt
VAR1="one two three"
VAR2="four five six"
VAR3="seven eight nine"
$ export d=`date +%Y-%m-%d` ; perl -p -i.old -e 'my $date = $ENV{d}; s/^VAR2(.*)"$/#VAR2\1" # $date\nVAR2\1 test" # $date/g' yourfile.txt
$ echo $?
0
$ cat yourfile.txt
VAR1="one two three"
#VAR2="four five six" # 2019-02-04
VAR2="four five six test" # 2019-02-04
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

If you want the "status" try this:

```
$ cat yourfile2.txt
VAR1="one two three"
VAR3="seven eight nine"
$ export d=`date +%Y-%m-%d` ; perl -p -i.old -e 'my $date = $ENV{d}; s/^VAR2(.*)"$/#VAR2\1" # $date\nVAR2\1 test" # $date/g' yourfile.txt ; grep "^VAR2" yourfile2.txt > /dev/null
$ echo $?
1
```

The `-i.old` this gives a backup file with the specify extension, if there were a change:

```
$ cat yourfile.txt.old
VAR1="one two three"
VAR2="four five six test"
VAR3="seven eight nine"
```

Comment: This doesn't let me know a status: yes it found the line and did the ask, or no it did not find the line.

Comment: You can get status with `grep`. Please see my update.

Comment: So `grep` is the only way? I was hoping `sed` might have a way to say if it found a match or not. Got it. Thanks!